# Android TextView mirroring (hud)?

Tags: android

I wondered if there could be a simple method to display a text contained in a TextView in such a way that it would have to be read in a mirror (like a head up display)?
By "simple method" I mean a way that would avoid a full rewrite of my app ;-)

Answer (score 2):

From what i've read so far, the only way to get a text mirrored is to override the `onDraw()` method. Not exactly a "simple way", but if you're up to it, [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) is probably the place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't sound as simple as I expected, but I think I'll give it a try...