# How to display in textView mirrored and inverted text?

Tags: java, android

I want to display in my textView mirrored and inverted text.
For exemple :[Second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Dwh.png)

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381329/mirrored-text-in-textview ??

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: try rotation attribute :-/